# Mockito void setter

Tags: mockito, void, setter

I have a class with a setter

```
 class X(){

    String a;

    void setA(String b){
    a=b;
    }
}
```

Then, when I mock like:

```
X instance;
instance = mock(X.class);

Mockito.when(instance.set(anyString()).thenCallRealMethod();
```

it complains about

`when (java.lang.Void) in Mockito cannot be applied to void`

How can I call the real method for a setter ?

Answer (score 0):

When you mock method it should be on Mocked object not the real instance.

```
@Mock
Instance instance;

@Test
public void testMyMethod(){
   doNothing().when(instance).setA(anyString());
   //....
}
```

or you can use @spy to partially mock real objects

```
@Spy
Instance instance = new Instance();

@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
 doNothing().when(instance).setA(anyString());
 //....
}
```

Comment: Why doNothing() and not doCallRealMethod() ?